# Running a laravel cron job (locally, to test) using Task Scheduler in Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I want to run a laravel cron job in order to run a command on windows 10 using task scheduler, I tried to create a basic task in scheduler but it shows running but data doesnt add in db. When I run "php artisan schedule:run" it works perfectly. I am using Laravel and Homestead.

[image: It shows this (see the pic please) but nothing happens then]

I have adding these two lines while creating the task in scheduler

C:\xampp\php\php.exe (why do we have to add this when I don't even use xampp anymore, so I think this is the part which is giving issues?????)

C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run

I would really appreciate, if someone could guide me through this, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your task scheduler command to this:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run
```

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe` does not mean using xampp, we're just using *php* here which is coincidentally found inside your xampp folder, because we need the executable php to run the file `artisan` with the parameter `schedule:run` which is found in `C:\projects\project-name\`

You can add an environment variable for your executable php so you could just write the command as `php C:\path\to\artisan schedule:run`.

Also, try to see the logs of task scheduler, so you can see what it tried to do.

As per your issue. Yes, `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` causes an issue. Try typing in your `cmd` that command. What happens? It's just paused there. That's also what's happening in your scheduled task.

Comment: alright, thanks for explaining it. Ill give it a try to what you said.

by typing C:\xampp\php\php.exe this command in cmd, nothing happens just a pause :/

C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run

used this in scheduler but all it does is open and closes the screen.

Comment: what happens when you type `php artisan schedule:run` in your laravel app? that should also happen when running the task. it's just like scheduling a cmd command, however, if the command has already finished, it is normal that the cmd will close.

Comment: TRIED EVERYTHING, NOTHING SEEMS TO WORK! and when i run php artisan schedule run, the task runs perfectly ( Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.1' 'artisan' SftpCommand:Sftp > '/dev/null' 2>&1 ). just with task scheduler it doesnt run.

Comment: when the task is ran, does it open a cmd? it it does, can you try appending `|| pause` to your task scheduler command so we can see what it does.

Comment: if i try ti run it manually from scheduler it opens the cmd as shown in the pic above, | | where should add this?

Comment: hi im sorry, my proxy blocks the image, i do not have any control over it. so I can't see it. however, if you run `php artisan schedule:run` is it a blocking process?

Comment: no worries, if i run php artisan schedule in vagrant the task runs perfectly. and in the picture it shows this msg: Running scheduled command: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" SftpCommand:Sftp > "NUL" 2>&1 and then the cmd closes itself

Comment: try to find logs of your task, so we can see the problem :)

Comment: in scheduler when i see the history it shows task completed each time i run it, 

Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Laravel", action "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" with return code 0.

maybe its a windows 10 bug or what :/ :S

Comment: why is the action only this? `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`? shouldn't it include the whole command which is `C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run`?

Comment: when i try to add: C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run in action then it automatically adds this C:\projects\project-name\artisan schedule:run to "add arguments" textbox

Comment: oh, so you're actually running the one that I've suggested to run. What should happen if your task was successfully ran? because it returns exit code of 0 meaning it succeeded.

Comment: yeap as you suggested I was running it that way anyways the task is suppose to delete a user with an id of 33. thats it :)

Comment: with php artisan schedule run in git bash it runs perfectly

Comment: where is your application served? because Windows and unix are different environments, I see that you use vagrant?

Comment: yeap, m using vagrant.

Comment: try creating the cron inside vagrant and let it run.

Comment: you mean adding * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
 in crontab? through vagrant?

Comment: yes, in your vagrant environment, not in your windows environment.

Comment: just add that line right? then do i have to run any command ? :)

Comment: * * * * * php /C:/projects/testproject/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

thats the line i added, the path I entered, thats how its supposed to be written?.. i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I think so. run `crontab -l` to make sure it was really registered.

Comment: so far it shows that the line i added is registered

Comment: nice, just wait for it to be triggered

Comment: Finally!!!!! it works, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciated. 
the windows task scheduler doesnt work which made me crazy anyways using vagrant does the job for now :)

And the path which i mentioned above doesnt do the job, the path re-entered was this * * * * * php /home/vagrant/code/testproject/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: yes, it wont really work because you're on different environments. glad it's working now :)

Comment: million thanks to your help ;D, ill just accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command,

```
php artisan schedule:work
```